# How to instantiate DataReceivedEventArgs or be able to fill it with data?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm starting a process and redirecting the error stream to be able to parse it and know what happened. I'm doing it this way:

```
_proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(NetErrorDataHandler);
```

Where NetErrorDataHandler has the following signature:

```
private void NetErrorDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs errLine)
```

So far I have to work with DataReceivedEventArgs, but I'm not sure how to test it.  Currently I'm running the process I'm working with. You can`t create instance of DataReceivedEventArgs with additional data, so how can I overcome this obstacle? The only way I see how to do this now is to create a process that would do the work for me. However, this isn't the best option for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What data does your application use out of DataReceivedEventArgs?

Your best solution may be to wrap DataReceivedEventArgs with a class that you are able to inject data into for testing and then pass that to an implementation method instead of doing all of your work inside of the current event handler.

Let me show you. First, create your custom wrapper class:

```
internal class CustomDataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{

    public string Data { get; set; }


    public CustomDataReceivedEventArgs(string _Data) 
    {
        Data = Data;
    }

    public CustomDataReceivedEventArgs(DataReceivedEventArgs Source) 
    {
        Data = Source.Data;
    }
}
```

Next, move your event handler impelmentation into the new method:

```
    private void NetErrorDataHandler_Implementation(object sendingProcess, 
        CustomDataReceivedEventArgs errLine) 
    {
        //Your actual event handling implementation here...
    }
```

Finally, set your event handler to do nothing but call the new method:

```
    private void NetErrorDataHandler(object sendingProcess, 
        DataReceivedEventArgs errLine)
    {
        NetErrorDataHandler_Implementation(sendingProcess, 
            new CustomDataReceivedEventArgs(errLine));
    }
```

Now, you can test your implementation by calling your implementation like this:

```
        NetErrorDataHandler_Implementation(new object(),
            new CustomDataReceivedEventArgs("My Test Data"));
```

Comment: Sorry, wrap with class. How is that? Actually my class is subscribing for DataReceivedEventHandler as you can see from the code. So it`s expecting concrete method signature to subscribe with. Even if datareceivedEventArgs is wrapped how can I use it if it`s always empty as it`s data property is readonly?

Comment: If there`ll be no other ideas I`ll mark it as solution. But I don`t like it as to test you`ll need to add special method signature that will work with CustomDataReceivedEventArgs to provide some data. But way to work with data is public interface. I don`t want to change it for testing purposes. So it will test my implementation but I need to create a special method for that and make it public.

Comment: I understand, this was just a quick and dirty way of getting around the unsettable data problem while making very few changes to your existing classes.

Comment: I don`t think there`s any other good solution. So thank you, I think yours is quite acceptable for testing purposes. What I did - just separated notifier from notifieble. Now notifier just get`s subscribes to process event and when he get`s it - notifies his curious object :-). And I can test how that curious object handles any data he receives as it`s ok for him to receive plain string.

Comment: That sounds like a fine solution - good use of the observer pattern.

Answer (score 8):

I just found out that it is possible to create objects with internal constructors and set the internal fields. Obviously, this is discouraged but it would work for short term mocking. Here's an example:

```
    private DataReceivedEventArgs CreateMockDataReceivedEventArgs(string TestData)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TestData))
            throw new ArgumentException("Data is null or empty.", "Data");

        DataReceivedEventArgs MockEventArgs =
            (DataReceivedEventArgs)System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices
             .GetUninitializedObject(typeof(DataReceivedEventArgs));

        FieldInfo[] EventFields = typeof(DataReceivedEventArgs)
            .GetFields(
                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        if (EventFields.Count() > 0)
        {
            EventFields[0].SetValue(MockEventArgs, TestData);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "Failed to find _data field!");
        }

        return MockEventArgs;

    }
```

Use as such:

```
DataReceivedEventArgs TestEventArgs = CreateMockDataReceivedEventArgs("Test");
```

...this took a bit of research, I didn't think it was possible :-)

Comment: This should be the answer.Impossible is nothing,thanks bro ;)

Comment: If you're going the route of reflection, you might as well invoke the ctor to initialize it, rather than modifying its internal state.